# Is there any energy loss if two blocks collide with a spring in between?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, energy-conservation, collision, spring

If two blocks collide with a spring in between, at the moment when the spring reaches max compression is any energy lost? One can look at it as an inelastic collision since the two blocks would be going at the same speed and then assume energy loss. But does the spring make a difference?

Comment: No energy is lost, kinetic becomes elastic potential energy

Comment: Energy is always lost in a real spring.  At closest approach, it is not an inelastic collision because the blocks are accelerating away from each other even though they are instantaneously stationary with respect to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In physics two bodies collide if the velocity (or momentum) of one body is changed due to other, now this does not mean that they need to be in contact.
Perfectly elastic collision is a collision in which there is 100% gain of kinetic energy which is converted into potential energy during collision. While perfectly inelastic collision means that there is no gain of kinetic energy (this does not mean that whole kinetic energy is lost). The gain or loss of kinetic energy is known by the coefficient of restitution($e$). The coefficient of restitution for perfectly elastic collision is 1 and that for perfectly inelastic collision is 0 but this does not mean that there is direct relation between coefficient of restitution and gain in kinetic energy. You can see this by the figure below.
[image]
Now for the case of spring between the two objects every thing wil be same instead the spring will deform in the place of the object themselves because perfectly elastic collision object regain their shape after deformation during collision while in perfectly inelastic collision they do not regain their shape but stick with each other. For the case of the spring in perfectly inelastic collision the spring will not regain it's original shape but will be locked in its max. compression. You can see this [post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/668957/relation-between-coefficient-of-restitution-and-k-e) for reference.
Hope it helps. :)
Edit:
The energy in a perfectly inelastic collision gets transferred to the surroundings of the system. In other words when there is a perfectly inelastic collision (as the name suggests it is between two inelastic bodies) the bodies cannot regain their shape because the are inelastic (for example: clay) and since they are inelastic they do not store any elastic potential energy in them. Same is for the spring if you are considering perfectly inelastic collision then the spring is inelastic or it cannot regain it's shape (which would violate the definition of the spring) and the energy lost in the collision will be transferred to the surroundings in other forms.

Comment: Thanks. I had a question, for a perfectly inelastic collision would the leftover energy be transferred to the spring? Or would some of the leftover energy be lost and some goes towards compressing the spring?

Comment: If you were able to understand correctly then please accept the answer by clicking the green tick on the left column

Comment: Yes it did and I did so. thanks again.